# T-SQL Sum Since Condition Last Met

Tags: t-sql, self-reference

I'm trying to do a sort of running total with a variable window size. I want to sum a value from the current row to the last time another row met a condition.

Mock Data: I want a formula for the last column

| ID | condition_col | col_to_sum | running_total_since_last_true |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | TRUE | 10 | 10 |
| 02 | FALSE | 8 | 18 |
| 03 | FALSE | 12 | 30 |
| 04 | TRUE | 5 | 5 |
| 05 | FALSE | 8 | 13 |
| 06 | FALSE | 10 | 23 |
| 07 | FALSE | -2 | 21 |
| 08 | TRUE | 1 | 1 |
| 09 | FALSE | 1 | 2 |

What I have tried:

```
select ID
     , condition_col
     , col_to_sum
     , (
        select sum(col_to_sum) as total
          from tbl t1
         where t1.ID between tbl.ID and (select top 1 t2.ID 
                                           from tbl t2 
                                          where condition_col = TRUE 
                                       order by t2.ID))
        ) as running_total_since_last_true
  from tbl
```

Because of the size of the dataset and the other things going on in the query (not shown here) this resulted in the query taking several minutes to run for a few thousand rows.

Now I'm looking at using sum() over(rows between current row and (select...)

I feel like I'm on the right track, but I keep getting stuck.

I also tried lag() but I couldn't make the lag reference itself properly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off putting your data into groups first and then using a cumulative `SUM`. You can put your data into groups by using a conditional cumulative `COUNT` (inside a CTE):

```sql
WITH Grps AS(
    SELECT ID,
           condition_col,
           col_to_sum,
           COUNT(CASE condition_col WHEN 'TRUE' THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC
                                                                  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Grp
    FROM (VALUES(01,'TRUE',10,10),
                (02,'FALSE',8,18),
                (03,'FALSE',12,30),
                (04,'TRUE',5,5),
                (05,'FALSE',8,13),
                (06,'FALSE',10,23),
                (07,'FALSE',-2,21),
                (08,'TRUE',1,1),
                (09,'FALSE',1,2))V(ID,condition_col,col_to_sum,running_total_since_last_true))
SELECT ID,
       condition_col,
       col_to_sum,
       SUM(col_to_sum) OVER (PARTITION BY Grp ORDER BY ID
                             ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS running_total_since_last_true
FROM Grps;
```

Comment: Perfect.

Not only did this solve the problem, but the total runtime for my query actually dropped somehow (compared to when I didn't include this column at all.) Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Heres some example DDL/DML:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID INT, condition_col BIT, col_to_sum INT);
INSERT INTO @Table (ID, condition_col, col_to_sum) VALUES 
(01, 1, 10), (02, 0, 8), (03, 0, 12), (04, 1, 5), (05, 0, 8), (06, 0, 10), (07, 0, -2), (08, 0, 1), (09, 0, 1);
```

It makes it much easier for folks to answer questions when we already have this.

This is a pretty typical problem, one way to solve it is using windowed functions:

```
SELECT ID, condition_col, col_to_sum, SUM(Col_To_Sum) OVER (PARTITION BY Cnt ORDER BY ID)
  FROM (
        SELECT ID, condition_col, col_to_sum, COUNT(CASE WHEN condition_col = 1 THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS cnt
          FROM @Table
       ) a
 ORDER BY id
```

Here we're using a windowed function to group the rows by an pseudo-ID, and then using that as the partition for the sum.

| ID | condition_col | col_to_sum | (No column name) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 10 |
| 2 | 0 | 8 | 18 |
| 3 | 0 | 12 | 30 |
| 4 | 1 | 5 | 5 |
| 5 | 0 | 8 | 13 |
| 6 | 0 | 10 | 23 |
| 7 | 0 | -2 | 21 |
| 8 | 0 | 1 | 22 |
| 9 | 0 | 1 | 23 |

Comment: Thank You! If I could check two solutions, I would. I ended up going with @Thom A 's solution because I was already working with WITH statements, and the real query was quite large and complex.

Re: DDL/DML Thanks for the Tip. Will do in the future.